# Circle, tangent, distances

Tags: geometry, circles

Straight line $L: 2x - y +k = 0$ is the tangent of a circle $C_1: x^2 +y^2 = 5$ , if $k <0$, What is the shortest distance between $L$ and another circle $C_2: (x+6)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 9$?

1. $3$
2. $3(5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
3. $3(5)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 3$
4. $3(5)^{\frac{1}{2}} + 3$

Comment: Random thoughts here: Changing the value of $k$ means generating parallel lines. There are exactly two values of $k$ for which the line is tangent to the circle. According to the question, one of the $k$ values has to be negative. When you solve the system of equations of the line intersecting with the circle, you obtain a quadratic equation. This equation has to have only one solution, which is the point of tangency. What does that mean for the discriminant of this equation? How does that help you to find the $k$'s?

Comment: I am getting $(14/\sqrt5)-3$, Pretty close to the 3rd option, lol

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Thoughtful questions, even homework-related, are welcome. However, you should not expect others to do your homework for you, and it's inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. (That may not be what you're doing, but all people here can go by is appearances.) Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand. Particularly, have you made a sketch?

Comment: Yes, I did make a sketch by hand, I guess i should find the right angle triangle to solve it, but then I can't find the right one to use. Sorry I will ask more specifically next time. Thx for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1) The center of $C_1$ is at $O(0, 0)$.

2) Let $R$ be the line parallel to $L: 2x – y + k = 0$ and passing through $O$. Find the equation of $R$.

3) Let $N$ be the line normal to $R$ and passes through $O$. Find the equation of $N$.

4) Find the points of tangency $K_1$ and $K_2$. Show that $K_2$ should be rejected.

5) If $L$ cuts the y-axis at $P$, then $OP =?$

6) Find $J$. From which, $QJ =?, QP =?$ And therefore $JP = ?$

Comment: thank you, the graph is really useful to solve the problem.

Comment: You are welcome.